# Bootstrap Collapse not working - ng-bootstrap included so no JQuery

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 8 project with Bootstrap 4.3.1 and ng-bootstrap 5.1.1.

My understanding is that once you include ng-bootstrap into your project then it is not necessary to manually add jQuery since it is encapsulated by ng-bootstrap so it is NOT included in my project.

**From the ng-bootstrap documentation:**

> Should I add bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to my project?
>
> No, the goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript
>   implementation for components. Nor should you include other
>   dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might
>   interfere with ng-bootstrap code.

So I added the Collapse component into my page but it does not work. I have seen in all questions on SO that the reason has always been that jQuery is missing, that's why I added the previous clarification.

The HTML in my component is as follows:

```
<article>
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-md-10">
        some content
      </section>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#details"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="details">
          <fa-icon class="col-md-2 clickable"
              [icon]="faCaretSquareDown" ></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" id="details">
        <section>
          some content
        </section>
        <section>
          some content
        </section>
        <section>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
        </section>
    </div>
</article>
```

So the question is, am I wrong in the original assumption about JQuery or is there something wrong in the way I have created this component?

**UPDATE**: I tried replacing all of this HTML with the Collapse example code from the Bootstrap docs and it didn't work either. So I am really confused as to what the problem may be. I also tried adding jQuery directly on the index page using the official CDN to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

These is a working example: [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)

html:

```
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
  [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-collapse-basic',
  templateUrl: './collapse-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdCollapseBasic {
  public isCollapsed = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. The thing is that I wasn't planning of adding ng-bootstrap to my project in the first place, I only did it because Bootstrap does not have a DatePicker so the idea was to use all of Bootstrap's components across the board and only use ng-bootstrap for the DatePicker. This NgbCollapse directive is from ng-bootstrap. Is there a way to make Bootstrap's Collapse component work?

Answer (score 0):

you need to ng bootstrap to ngModule,
link:[link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

like this:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
 ...
 imports: [NgbModule, ...],
 ...
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```